# Truncation Issue with SMTP.office365.com in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, office365

**Issue**:
While sending emails using smtp.office365.com in a Codeigniter 3 application, the email body text is being truncated. The email body contains HTML, and even simple text messages are not being sent properly. Interestingly, sending from other servers' SMTP does not result in this issue.

SMTP Settings:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587'; // if 80 doesn't work, try 24 or 21
$config['smtp_user']  = 'noreply@domain.com';  
$config['smtp_pass']  = '*******';  
$config['_smtp_auth'] = true;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls'; 
$config['mailtype']  = 'html'; 
$config['charset']    = 'UTF-8'; 
$config['wordwrap']   = TRUE;
```

**Problem**:
The received email body text is as follows. The problematic parts have been highlighted.

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. **=orem** Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500=, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
> scrambled it to make **a=ype** specimen book. It has survived not only
> five centuries, but also the **=eap** into electronic typesetting,
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was **p=pularised** in the 1960s with
> the release of Letraset sheets containing Lore= Ipsum passages, and
> more recently with desktop publishing software like **A=dus** PageMaker
> including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

**Question**:
What could be causing this issue, either on the application or SMTP server side? Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting and resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if your email body has very long lines without breaks.

Comment: nope, even one paragraph as copied above

Comment: Check the email source, headers, etc. anything interesting there?

Comment: Ensure `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';` in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: Print the email body for debugging `echo $this->email->message();` , instead of send

Comment: @shirshak007 upon printing it is perfect, and yes charset is all fine, tested with different charset options as well like UTF-16, Windows-1252,ISO-8859-6 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the config you have, add these two more `newline` and `clrf`

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

This problem is caused because of the `Quoted-printable` encoding. I hope now it will work as expected

Comment: Absolute! Thanks